# Simple Jquery Ajax request Laravel.. Error Code:500

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am testing some simple ajax request and i am getting error code 500 while trying to response with controller
Internal Server Error 500

My web.php file

```
 This one works fine
//Route::get('/test', function () {
//    return "i am a success get";
//});  

I cannot seem to get this one to work
Route::get('/test', 'shoppingCartController@testfunction');
```

My Controller

```
class shoppingCartController extends Controller
{
    public function testfunction(Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
//        
//        if ($request->isMethod('post')){    
//            return response()->json(['response' => 'This is post method']); 
//        }
//
//        return response()->json(['response' => 'This is get method']);
//         
        return 'test';
    }
}
```

And my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "test", success: function(result){
                $("#div1").html(result);
            }, error: function(xhr){
                $("#div1").html(xhr.statusText + " " + xhr.status);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: does it work without ajax ?

Comment: What method is your AJAX call using? If it is using `POST` then you will get an error. If you use your dev tools in your browser you will be able to see the actual error message.

Comment: use firebug to see actual error message and post it here. add `/` on ajax url make it `/test`. Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the answer is as  n00dl3  suggested the controller was not working without ajax also. It seems i was getting

```
Illuminate\Http\Request not found exception
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for ajax call:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var urla = {!! json_encode(url('/')) !!};
     jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: urla + '/test',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {logtype: type},
            success: function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            },
        });
</script>
```

And set the 'test' method as:

```
Route::get('/test', 'TestController@test');
```

Here change the `TestController` to that controller where you have put the `test` method.

Ofcourse you can add error clause in the ajax call. here I just added `console.log(msg)` where `msg` is json encoded response.